# Rails: attr_accessor association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

Hello I am beginner for rails.

I have two models `UserSubscriptions` and `SubscriptionPlan`.

`user_subscription.rb`

```
class  UserSubscription < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :new_plan_id
 
  belongs_to :subscription_plan
  belongs_to :new_plan_id, class_name: 'SubscriptionPlan', foreign_key: :new_plan_id
end
```

`subscription_plan.rb`

```
class SubscriptionPlan < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_subscriptions
end
```

I want to get `new_plan` as an object of `subscription_plan` model. Still I am unable to get this. Plz help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Remove the attr accessor, and bettetlr do it belongs_to :new_plan (without the id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never want to use `attr_accessor` in Rails models.*

`attr_accessor` is used in plain old ruby objects to generate accessor methods for instance variables. If you use `attr_accessor` in a Rails model you're clobbering the setter and getter that it creates from reading the database schema.

The result is that the attribute will not be persisted when you save. This is because the attrbute is not stored in the attributes hash and is not marked as dirty. It also won't be included in any of the methods that use the attributes api such as `#attributes` or `#to_json`.

It will also break the association as well.

```
class  UserSubscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subscription_plan
  belongs_to :new_plan, class_name: 'SubscriptionPlan'
end
```

Comment: * Well almost never. The rare exception is if you just want an instance variable and not something that behaves like a attribute.

Comment: Thanks @max. I have one more question. Is there any need to declare association into other model. vice versa?

Comment: I mean is there need to add association into SubscriptionPlan model?

Comment: Yes, you need to declare associations on both sides if you actually want to be able to use the association from that model. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association